# Laravel validation on two columns

Tags: php, laravel

I have contacts table with field email and alteranate_email. While adding new contact i want to check email address should not present in either email or alteranate_email.  For Example, There is contact present  with alteranate_email = 'abc@example.com'. When I  tried to add new contact with email = 'abc@example.com', it allows me to add new contact.

I have tried below code but its not working.

```
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => ['nullable', 'email',
                 Rule::unique('contacts')->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                     return $query->where('email', $request->email)->orWhere('alteranate_email', $request->email);
                 }),
            ],

        ]);
```

Comment: 'email' => 'nullable|email|unique: contacts.email,alteranate_email'

Comment: no it doesnt work

Comment: why it is not working? what error do you get?

Comment: it allows me to add new contact even if email address present in alternate email address field.

Comment: remove whitespace between `unique:` and `contacts` - `'email' => 'nullable|email|unique:contacts.email,alteranate_email' `

Comment: now it gives me error `Database [ contacts] not configured.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to use two `unique` instead of making new rule. Try these one line solution below.

```
'email' => 'nullable|email|unique:contacts,email|unique:contacts,alternate_email'
```